# Hexagonal architecture with Spring and modules

Tags: java, spring, maven, architecture, microservices

I am trying to implement [Hexagonal architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) over Spring Boot application with multiple `Maven` modules. The main idea to depend on abstractions, not concretions.
I created three modules **test-core**, **test-adapter**, **test-application** basically as described [here](https://github.com/gshaw-pivotal/spring-hexagonal-example):

```
┌ \ pom.xml
├ \ test-core
│   ├  pom.xml
│   └─ src\com\example\core\
|                      ├─ ConfigCore.java
|                      └─ FooService.java
├ \ test-adapter
│   ├  pom.xml
|   └─ src\com\example\adapter\
|                      ├─ ConfigAdapter.java
|                      └─ FooServiceImpl.java
└ \ test-application
    ├  pom.xml
    └─ src\com\example\
               ├─ ConfigApplication.java
               └─ Application.java
```

The main idea is to have next dependencies:

- **test-adapter** depends from **test-core**
- **test-application** depends from **test-core**

and that's all. However it's not possible to implement without third dependency where **test-application** depends from **test-adapter**. In given example, which I used they did it by this way (added direct dependency). However I would like to avoid this, as I want to have architect design without such coupling.
Is it possible to implement somehow? Or I want too much? Or I incorrectly understand Ports-And-Adapters architecture?

To make issue more clear, below you can find code. **FooServices.java**

```
package com.example.core;
public interface FooService { String execute(); }
```

**FooServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.adapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import com.example.core.FooService;
@Service
@Qualifier("fooService")
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    public String execute() { return "Hello world!"; }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package com.example;
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example"})
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fooService")
    FooService fooService;

    public static void main(String[] args) { SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); }
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) { return args -> { System.out.println(fooService.execute()); }; }
}
```

without written dependency in **\ test-application \ pom.xml** to **test-adapter**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I constantly receive next error

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fooService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.core.FooService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=fooService)}

As you see `@Qualifier` annotation doesn't help here. `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})`, `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example"})` as well.

Solution is to implement next steps:
**ConfigCore.java**

```
package com.example.core;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.core"})
public class ConfigCore { }
```

**ConfigAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.adapter;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.adapter"})
public class ConfigAdapter { }
```

**ConfigApplication.java**

```
package com.example;
import com.example.core.ConfigCore;
import com.example.adapter.ConfigAdapter;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@Import({ConfigCore.class, ConfigAdapter.class})
public class ConfigApplication { }
```

and put corresponding dependency (mentioned above) to **pom.xml**. In that case everything works fine. However, as I mentioned I don't think that this is correct approach. Could you help me with understanding of possibilities to remove this dependency between **test-adapter** and **test-application** ?

Comment: Avoid being unnecessarily specific, such as using `Qualifier` unless you have a known conflict to manage.

Comment: Did you try using `<scope>runtime</scope>` instead of `<scope>compile</scope>`? This should work. Verify that the `test-adapter` classes are available on the Claspath when you run it.

Comment: @chrylis, sure, @Qualifier is the only example to one who can suggest such approach. @Neo, I am not quite sure, that I got your point. It works with `<scope>compile</scope>` without an issue. My idea to do not have such dependency at all, doesn't matter scope of it. Do you think it's impossible to get rid of such relation?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to hexagonal architecture.

The SpringBootApplication will need in the classpath all the beans to be exposed in the ApplicationContext.

I suppose in your case, this class is located in **test-application**.
If you don't put any dependency to **test-adapter**, the Configurations will not be loaded, so your ComponentScan has no effect.

Even magic autoconfigured beans in SpringBoot have to be declared at least in runtime scope in your pom.xml

Moreover in Hexagonal Architecture implementation, we usually use the application module to compose the bean injection strategy. So you should put your configurations inside this layer.

The adapters are used to interact with you domain, like a Rest layer for example.

The given [hexagonal architecture implementation example](https://gitlab.com/crafts-records/talkadvisor/talkadvisor-back/tree/master/talkadvisor-infra/talkadvisor-infra-application/src/main/kotlin/org/craftsrecords/talkadvisor/infra) has a single module where the application and the adapters are gathered. But if you want to split it, you'll basically get:

- in an application module: the configurations and the *Application
- in a youtube adapter: the youtube package (SPI in that case)
- in a rest adapter: the controller and the resources

But the application module will have to get a dependency on each adapter.

The main purpose of the [hexagonal architecture](https://beyondxscratch.com/2017/08/19/decoupling-your-technical-code-from-your-business-logic-with-the-hexagonal-architecture-hexarch/) is the decoupling of the business logic from the technical part. Nothing states that an adapter should be standalone, but it can be your implementation choice anyway :)

Comment: Another good example for creating Hexagonal architecture with Spring Boot:
https://github.com/sofieneBK/hands-on-hexagonal-architecture-with-spring-boot

The adapter and port have only the dependencies with the domain; The application module (with Spring boot laucher) has the dependencies with all the adapters

Comment: @Julien "Nothing states that an adapter should be standalone" : yes it does, the "application" and "infrastructure" layers should ideally depend only the "domain" layer. It would be useful to be able to do so with Spring, so that your new trainee doesn't is not tempted to inject a repository directly in a controller  ;)

Comment: @Sav74 No, the application module depends only on the domain module. There is an additional "spring-launcher" module which depends on all modules to allow the spring wiring.